# How can I fetch data from Map<Point2D,Float>

Tags: java, dictionary

I'm a beginner in java. Here is my question:
How can I aggregate all points from `Map<Point2D, Float>` relative to Float value (z-axis) ?

Here is how I create the Map:

```java
Map<Point2D, Float> coordinates = new HashMap<Point2D, Float>();
```

I want to get all Point2D (x,y) which are on Float z-coord. (z-axis)

For example

```
<(x=1,y=2),z=3>
<(x=2,y=2),z=3>
<(x=5,y=6),z=3>
<(x=5,y=2),z=4>
```

And I want to get all points where z=3 so it should be 1,2,3rd and save it in an `ArrayList`.

Comment: You will need to be much more specific about what you want to accomplish.

Comment: @ajb I want to get all points which are on z axis (float value)

Comment: That isn't really any more specific.  Please provide an example of how you have set up your `Map`, with an example of what you want to create.  Do you want to create an array, a `List`, or some other data structure, and what values do you want in it?

Comment: @ajb i've edited it. Take a look on this.

Comment: Why are you not just storing 3D points instead?

Comment: @will becouse in next step i have to implement convex hull algorithm for all 2d points on z-axis ,ex. for all 2d points where z equals 2 :)

Comment: @JanKowalski Thank you.  That's about the level of detail we need.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the data structure, then you'll just need to iterate through the `map` and take all the `entrySet`s you need;

```
for (Map.Entry<Point2D, Float> coordinateFloat: coordinates.entrySet()) {
    Point2D point = coordinateFloat.getKey();
    Float z = coordinateFloat.getValue();
    // ... Now you can test for z, and add the points to some other list.
}
```

Since you're operating on all the 2D points on each xy plane `z=Z`, you could store the data in this way;

```
Map<Float, ArrayList<Point2D> > coordinates = new HashMap<Float, ArrayList<Point2D> >();
```

This way, you can then fairly easily iterate through all the xy planes, and do your convex hull algorithms on the point collections;

```
for(Map.entry<Float, ArrayList<Point2D>> coordinatesOnPlane : coordinates.entrySet()){
    Float z = coordinatesOnPlane.getKey();
    for(Point2D point : coordinatesOnPlane.getValue()){
        //... act on points, or whatever.
    }
}
```